# Is there any way for "make" to echo commands

Tags: makefile

Is there a way to have `make` echo commands that are manually suppressed with `@` in the makefile? I can't find this in the help or man page, it just says "--quiet" to do the opposite.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I force make/gcc to show me the commands?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5820303/how-do-i-force-make-gcc-to-show-me-the-commands)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

- The most obvious idea is to change the shell that runs the commands, e.g. modify your makefile and add to the top `SHELL = sh -xv`.
- Another solution is to change how you call make to `make SHELL='sh -xv'`
- Lastly if your Makefile is generated by `cmake` then call `make` with `make VERBOSE=1`

Comment: I found out that the nVidia SDK makefiles actually have a VERBOSE option (so make VERBOSE= works), but this is an awesome and more general solution! Thanks!

Comment: SHELL = sh -xv isn't doing anything for me. neither (SHELL="sh -xv" make) nor (export SHELL="sh -xv" && make)

Comment: @gman: You need it to include it into the make command (`make SHELL='sh -xv'` or into the Makefile.

Comment: `-v` had no effect on Dash 0.5.7 (Ubuntu 14.04), I think because it ignores `-c` commands, which is how `Make` must be running them. Works for GNU Bash though.

Comment: A side effect of this approach is that it echoes any function exports that may be in the user's `.bashrc` contents for each shell instantiation.

Comment: If using parallel building `-j#`, then the output may not be what you expect due to race conditions between spawned shells.

Answer (score 11):

I run into this question from time to time using cmake because it hides the command. You can use "make VERBOSE=true" to get them to print out.

Comment: Thanks, I did find this out for the SDK.

Comment: This entirely depends on the Makeflile at hand.