# How do I force make/GCC to show me the commands?

Tags: gcc, makefile, verbosity

I'm trying to debug a compilation problem, but I cannot seem to get GCC (or maybe it is make??) to show me the actual compiler and linker commands it is executing.

Here is the output I am seeing:

```
  CCLD   libvirt_parthelper
libvirt_parthelper-parthelper.o: In function `main':
/root/qemu-build/libvirt-0.9.0/src/storage/parthelper.c:102: undefined reference to `ped_device_get'
/root/qemu-build/libvirt-0.9.0/src/storage/parthelper.c:116: undefined reference to `ped_disk_new'
/root/qemu-build/libvirt-0.9.0/src/storage/parthelper.c:122: undefined reference to `ped_disk_next_partition'
/root/qemu-build/libvirt-0.9.0/src/storage/parthelper.c:172: undefined reference to `ped_disk_next_partition'
/root/qemu-build/libvirt-0.9.0/src/storage/parthelper.c:172: undefined reference to `ped_disk_next_partition'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[3]: *** [libvirt_parthelper] Error 1
```

What I want to see should be similar to this:

```
$ make
gcc -Wall   -c -o main.o main.c
gcc -Wall   -c -o hello_fn.o hello_fn.c
gcc   main.o hello_fn.o   -o main
```

Notice how this example has the complete `gcc` command displayed. The above example merely shows things like "CCLD   libvirt_parthelper". I'm not sure how to control this behavior.

Comment: Are you running a makefile, or just a `gcc` command?

Comment: This looks like [Kbuild](https://www.kernel.org/doc/linux/README) or [Autotools](https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Automake-Silent-Rules.html) output. Try ***`make V=1`***.

Comment: Related: the opposite question [Control the output of a make command to be less verbose, don't echo each command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8438661/control-the-output-of-a-make-command)

Answer (score 387):

To invoke a **dry run**:

```
make -n
```

This will show what `make` is attempting to do.

Comment: Found it :)

    make V=1

Although the above suggestion of "make -n" worked as well. :)

Thank you all for your responses.

Comment: Difference is that `make -n` does not execute the commands. Thus correct answer is `make V=1`

Comment: `make V=1` is only working if the Makefile supports it.  automake's makefiles do that, but many others don't.

Comment: For CMake, use `make VERBOSE=1`; for GNU autotools `make V=1`.

Comment: @m-ric if you want to run actually run the commands, consider `make SHELL='sh -x'`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32010960/895245

Comment: running with `make -k` helped me (`-k` = `--keep running`)

Comment: This never works in a recursive environment (like `./configure` or `cmake` generate).

Answer (score 255):

**Build system independent method**

```
make SHELL='sh -x'
```

is another option. Sample `Makefile`:

```
a:
    @echo a
```

Output:

```
+ echo a
a
```

This sets the special `SHELL` variable for `make`, and `-x` tells `sh` to print the expanded line before executing it.

One advantage over `-n` is that is actually runs the commands. I have found that for some projects (e.g. Linux kernel) that `-n` may stop running much earlier than usual probably because of dependency problems.

One downside of this method is that you have to ensure that the shell that will be used is `sh`, which is the default one used by Make as they are POSIX, but could be changed with the `SHELL` make variable.

Doing `sh -v` would be cool as well, but Dash 0.5.7 (Ubuntu 14.04 `sh`) ignores for `-c` commands (which seems to be how `make` uses it) so it doesn't do anything.

`make -p` will also interest you, which prints the values of set variables.

**CMake generated Makefiles always support `VERBOSE=1`**

As in:

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
make VERBOSE=1
```

Dedicated question at: [Using CMake with GNU Make: How can I see the exact commands?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2670121/using-cmake-with-gnu-make-how-can-i-see-the-exact-commands)

Comment: Definitely the best answer which doesn't depend on how well the original Makefile was written/generated

Comment: If anyone can explain the downvote, let me know so I can learn and improve the information ;-)

Comment: make `SHELL='$$SHELL -x'` will make `$SHELL` literal which is not evaluated. Using `make SHELL="$SHELL -x"` will work.

Comment: this is the best generic answer, in contrast to some other answers this does not depend on using cmake

Comment: make SHELL='sh -x' is super!

Comment: Good idea (`SHELL='sh -x'`), but if your makefiles were to pass `SHELL` around, they must do it like so: `SHELL='$(SHELL)'`, not `SHELL=$(SHELL)`. So you might need to do some replacements.

Comment: I don't know why the downvote, but there should be a makefile interface that can circumvent this.  There are many options as expressed in other posts.  However, the makefile may contain `make help`, which would give instruction on how to get verbose output.  Using the `sh -x`  could break a makefile if it wanted `bash` for instance.  There is no right answer.  I always take a negative vote as a fact that I may have stretched someone's mind and they didn't like it.

Comment: `SHELL += -x` might be a better tack.

Answer (score 215):

Library makefiles, which are generated by autotools (the `./configure` you have to issue) often have a verbose option, so basically, using `make VERBOSE=1` or `make V=1` should give you the full commands.

But this depends on how the makefile was generated.

The `-d` option might help, but it will give you an extremely long output.

Comment: Note: CMake-generated Makefiles only support `VERBOSE=1`, not `V=1`.

Comment: V=1 worked for me, compiling nuttx with mips-linux-gnu-gcc, thank you.

Answer (score 38):

Since GNU Make version 4.0, the `--trace` argument is a nice way to tell what and why a makefile do, outputing lines like:

```
makefile:8: target 'foo.o' does not exist
```

or

```
makefile:12: update target 'foo' due to: bar
```

Comment: This argument prints more detailed information than dry run. It is very helpful to understand make systems which has complex build process like dpdk.

Comment: @makerj: Perhaps, but it does actually execute the commands, unlike `make -n`.

Answer (score 31):

Use `make V=1`

Other suggestions here:

- `make VERBOSE=1` - did not work at least from my trials.
- `make -n` - displays only logical operation, not command line being executed. E.g. `CC source.cpp`
- `make --debug=j` - works as well, but might also enable multi threaded building, causing extra output.

Comment: `make VERBOSE=1` is for CMake. Your trials were most likely with GNU autotools-based projects.

Answer (score 17):

I like to use:

```
make --debug=j
```

https://linux.die.net/man/1/make

--debug[=FLAGS]

Print debugging information in addition to normal processing. If the FLAGS are omitted, then the behavior is the same as if `-d` was specified. FLAGS may be a for all debugging output (same as using `-d`), `b` for basic debugging, `v` for more verbose basic debugging, `i` for showing implicit rules, **`j` for details on invocation of commands**, and `m` for debugging while remaking makefiles.

Comment: It doesn't necessarily show the command it executes. You may just get `Reaping winning child  xyz` and `Jobserver client (fds 3,4)` and `Need a job token; we don't have children` and so on.

Comment: Agreed, @einpoklum.

Answer (score 17):

Depending on your automake version, you can also use this:

```
make AM_DEFAULT_VERBOSITY=1
```

Reference: *[AM_DEFAULT_VERBOSITY](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-autoconf/2012-01/msg00007.html)*

*Note: I added this answer since `V=1` did not work for me.*

Answer (score 3):

- In case you want to see all commands (including the compiled ones) of the default target run:

```bash
make --always-make --dry-run
make -Bn
```

- show commands executed the next run of `make`:

```bash
make --dry-run
make -n
```

You are free to choose a target other than the default in this example.