# What are the codes such as CC, LD and CC[M] output when compiling the Linux kernel?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, makefile, kbuild

While compiling Linux from scratch I realize that there are compile codes that appear while compiling.

For example CC filename , LD filename, CC[M] filename.

What do these codes mean?

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/199060/what-do-the-terms-cc-ld-and-shipped-refer-to-during-the-kernel-source-compilati

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The different markings specify the following

- [CC] - Compiles the C file into an designated object file. The object file contains the archicture assembler code of that .c file. As it might also reference parts outside its scope. For example calling another function in another .c file. The function calls are left open within the object file, which is later included by the linker. Therefore
- [LD] is the proces of linking the compiled objects together, and wire up the function calls that has been left open by the compiler. However, many parts are linked together as the core part of the kernel, while some parts are left out. And thus you see
- [CC (M)] for those parts which are compiled as points to be loaded into the kernel at runtime. But which are not linked together in the monolithic part of the kernel. But instead can be inserted when the kernel is booted.

Comment: IOW, in CC [M], the M stands for 'modules' as the source files are ultimately compiled into a loadable kernel module, an object file with the .ko extension

Comment: Is this documented somewhere? Because I also see codes like `AR` not listed here.

Answer (score 10):

Let's take an specific example and figure out what it does in the kernel 4.1, e.g. `IHEX`.

**Find what a code does**

Just run:

```
make SHELL='sh -x'
```

How that works: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32010960/895245

If we grep the output for `IHEX`, we find the lines:

```
+ echo   IHEX    firmware/e100/d101s_ucode.bin
  IHEX    firmware/e100/d101s_ucode.bin
+ objcopy -Iihex -Obinary /home/ciro/git/kernel/src/firmware/e100/d101s_ucode.bin.ihex firmware/e100/d101s_ucode.bin
```

so we conclude that `IHEX` does a `objcopy -Iihex`.

**Find where a code is defined**

Every kernel command must be defined with something like:

```
quiet_cmd_ihex  = IHEX    $@
      cmd_ihex  = $(OBJCOPY) -Iihex -Obinary $< $@

$(obj)/%: $(obj)/%.ihex
        $(call cmd,ihex)
```

for the verbosity settings (e.g. `V=1` and `make -s`) to work.

So in general, you just have to

```
git grep 'cmd.* = CODE'
```

to find `CODE`.

I have explained in detail how this system works at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32023861/895245

**Get the list of all codes**

```
make | grep -E '^  ' | sort -uk1,1
```

**CC and CC [M]**

Defined in `scripts/Makefile.build`:

```
quiet_cmd_cc_o_c = CC $(quiet_modtag)  $@
      cmd_cc_o_c = $(CC) $(c_flags) -c -o $@ $<
```

and the `[M]` comes from the [target specific variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32023711/what-is-the-meaning-of-a-variable-defined-on-the-same-line-of-a-rule-targets-pre):

```
$(real-objs-m)        : quiet_modtag := [M]
$(real-objs-m:.o=.i)  : quiet_modtag := [M]
$(real-objs-m:.o=.s)  : quiet_modtag := [M]
$(real-objs-m:.o=.lst): quiet_modtag := [M]
$(obj-m)              : quiet_modtag := [M]
```

It is then called through:

```
$(obj)/%.o: $(src)/%.c $(recordmcount_source) FORCE
    [...]
    $(call if_changed_rule,cc_o_c)

define rule_cc_o_c
    [...]
    $(call echo-cmd,cc_o_c) $(cmd_cc_o_c);                \
```

where `if_changed_rule` is defined in `scripts/Kbuild.include` as:

```
if_changed_rule = $(if $(strip $(any-prereq) $(arg-check) ),                 \
    @set -e;                                                             \
    $(rule_$(1)))
```

and `Kbuild.include` gets included on the top level Makefile.

**LD**

There are a few versions, but the simplest seems to be:

```
quiet_cmd_link_o_target = LD      $@
cmd_link_o_target = $(if $(strip $(obj-y)),\
              $(LD) $(ld_flags) -r -o $@ $(filter $(obj-y), $^) \
              $(cmd_secanalysis),\
              rm -f $@; $(AR) rcs$(KBUILD_ARFLAGS) $@)

$(builtin-target): $(obj-y) FORCE
    $(call if_changed,link_o_target)
```

and in `scripts/Kbuild.include`:

```
# Execute command if command has changed or prerequisite(s) are updated.
#
if_changed = $(if $(strip $(any-prereq) $(arg-check)),                       \
    @set -e;                                                             \
    $(echo-cmd) $(cmd_$(1));                                             \
    printf '%s\n' 'cmd_$@ := $(make-cmd)' > $(dot-target).cmd)
```

Answer (score 4):

It should show:

- `CC` when compiling a core part of the kernel
- `CC [M]` when compiling a module
- `LD` when linking