# In Kernel makefile $(call cmd, tags) what is the cmd here refers to?

Tags: makefile, linux-kernel, kernel, kbuild

In Kernel Makefile i found the code like below:

```
ctags CTAGS CSCOPE: $(HEADERS) $(SOURCES) 

$(ETAGS) $(ETAGSFALGS) $(HEADERS) $(SOURCES)

$(call cmd, ctags)
```

Also, where can i find the Macro or function ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using MadScientist's method on kernel v4.1:

```
make -p | grep -B1 -E '^cmd '
```

we find:

```
# makefile (from `scripts/Kbuild.include', line 211)
cmd = @$(echo-cmd) $(cmd_$(1))
```

`scripts/Kbuild.include` is included on the top level `Makefile`. It also contains:

```
echo-cmd = $(if $($(quiet)cmd_$(1)),\
    echo '  $(call escsq,$($(quiet)cmd_$(1)))$(echo-why)';)
```

- `quiet`: set at the top level makefile, depending on the value of `V`.

  Will be either:

  - `quiet_` to print `CC file.c`
  - empty to print the command on `V=`
  - `silent_` to not print anything on `make -s`
- `escsq` is defined as:

  ```
  squote  := '
  escsq = $(subst $(squote),'\$(squote)',$1)
  ```

  It escapes single quotes so that `echo '$(call escsq,Letter 'a'.'` will print properly in `sh`.
- `echo-why`: defined further down at `Kbuild.include`.

  It is used for `make V=2`, and says why a target is being remade.

The setup of `make tags` is done in the `Makefile`:

```
quiet_cmd_tags = GEN     $@
      cmd_tags = $(CONFIG_SHELL) $(srctree)/scripts/tags.sh $@

tags TAGS cscope gtags: FORCE
    $(call cmd,tags)
```

Which shows the typical usage pattern for calling commands on kbuild:

```
quiet_cmd_XXX = NAME     $@
      cmd_XXX = actual-command $@

target: prerequisites
    $(call cmd,tags)
```

A comment on the `Makefile` explains how all of this is done to make the `make` output prettier:

```
# Beautify output
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#
# Normally, we echo the whole command before executing it. By making
# that echo $($(quiet)$(cmd)), we now have the possibility to set
# $(quiet) to choose other forms of output instead, e.g.
#
#         quiet_cmd_cc_o_c = Compiling $(RELDIR)/$@
#         cmd_cc_o_c       = $(CC) $(c_flags) -c -o $@ $<
```

Answer (score 2):

If you run `make -p` it will print the entire database of all variables, rules, etc. with line numbers where they were last defined.