# What is the meaning of a variable defined on the same line of a rule targets prerequisites such as "a: x = 0" in GNU Make?

Tags: makefile

I have seen code like the following following code in a Makefile:

```
a: x = 0
```

What does this line mean? Is it a rule, or something else?

Comment: If anyone can understand the downvote, please let me know. I want to learn to improve. I never retaliate downvoters who explain. Self answered to help other people in the world gain 15 minutes in their lives by googling keywords :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is called a target specific variable, see: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Target_002dspecific.html

It gives a different value to a variable inside a given target.

Sample usage:

```
x := 0

a: x := 1
a:
    @echo $x

b:
    @echo $x
```

Now:

```
$ make a
1
$ make b
0
```