# linker unused command with clang++ 8

Tags: c++, clang++

I'm using the code of this [this tutorial](https://github.com/google/filament/blob/master/filament/README.md#linking-against-filament) to link a simple main function with the filament library.

The folder structure is:

```
|-- README.md
|-- bin
|-- docs
|-- include
|-- lib
|-- main.cpp
```

And I've unrolled the contento the makefile as follow:

`/usr/bin/clang-cpp-8 main.cpp -L./lib/x86_64/ -I./include -lfilament -lbluegl -lbluevk -lfilabridge -lfilaflat -lutils -lpthread -lc++ -ldl -lm -std=c++14 -pthread -c`

But when I run that line, or the original makefile I get:

```
clang: warning: -lfilament: 'linker' input unused in cpp mode [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
clang: warning: -lbluegl: 'linker' input unused in cpp mode [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
clang: warning: -lbluevk: 'linker' input unused in cpp mode [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
clang: warning: -lfilabridge: 'linker' input unused in cpp mode [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
clang: warning: -lfilaflat: 'linker' input unused in cpp mode [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
clang: warning: -lutils: 'linker' input unused in cpp mode [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
clang: warning: -lpthread: 'linker' input unused in cpp mode [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
clang: warning: -lc++: 'linker' input unused in cpp mode [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
clang: warning: -ldl: 'linker' input unused in cpp mode [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
clang: warning: -lm: 'linker' input unused in cpp mode [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-L./lib/x86_64/' [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
```

plus for some reason the following output (Only partial because is too long)

```
# 1 "main.cpp"
# 1 "<built-in>" 1
# 1 "<built-in>" 3
# 389 "<built-in>" 3
# 1 "<command line>" 1
# 1 "<built-in>" 2
# 1 "main.cpp" 2
# 1 "./include/filament/FilamentAPI.h" 1
# 20 "./include/filament/FilamentAPI.h"
# 1 "./include/utils/compiler.h" 1
# 21 "./include/filament/FilamentAPI.h" 2

# 1 "/usr/include/clang/8.0.0/include/stddef.h" 1 3
# 51 "/usr/include/clang/8.0.0/include/stddef.h" 3
typedef long int ptrdiff_t;
# 62 "/usr/include/clang/8.0.0/include/stddef.h" 3
typedef long unsigned int size_t;
# 118 "/usr/include/clang/8.0.0/include/stddef.h" 3
# 1 "/usr/include/clang/8.0.0/include/__stddef_max_align_t.h" 1 3
# 35 "/usr/include/clang/8.0.0/include/__stddef_max_align_t.h" 3
typedef struct {
  long long __clang_max_align_nonce1
      __attribute__((__aligned__(__alignof__(long long))));
  long double __clang_max_align_nonce2
      __attribute__((__aligned__(__alignof__(long double))));
} max_align_t;
# 119 "/usr/include/clang/8.0.0/include/stddef.h" 2 3
# 23 "./include/filament/FilamentAPI.h" 2

namespace filament {







class __attribute__((visibility("default"))) FilamentAPI {
protected:

    FilamentAPI() noexcept = default;
    ~FilamentAPI() = default;
```

There's no much indication of what the error could be, can anyone help?

For reference the Makefile:

```
FILAMENT_LIBS=-lfilament -lbluegl -lbluevk -lfilabridge -lfilaflat -lutils
CC=clang++

main: main.o
    $(CC) -Llib/x86_64/ main.o $(FILAMENT_LIBS) -lpthread -lc++ -ldl -o main

main.o: main.cpp
    $(CC) -Iinclude/ -std=c++14 -pthread -c main.cpp

clean:
    rm -f main main.o

.PHONY: clean
```

Comment: You command compiles code, e.g. produces an `.o` file. This is what happens when `-c` flag is passed to compiler. Linker is not used at this step and you got such warnings.

Comment: But isn't the make file supposed to produce an executable? As far as I can see it should, but it doesn't. Are you saying the warnings are normal then?

Comment: Makefile runs commands which create targets like `main` and `main.o` in your case.

> And I've unrolled the contento the makefile as follow:

How did you do this? Mostly curios. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5820303/how-do-i-force-make-gcc-to-show-me-the-commands

You probably just run your original command without `-c` flag and in a good case command will produce executable named `a.out`.

Comment: Literally I've substituted the variables and run as a single command. I didn't spot the `-c` flag, but anyway... As I said using the makefile doesn't make any difference. There's no executable produced. And I'm trying to figure why...

Comment: Also if in the makefile I comment `main: main.o
 $(CC) -L./lib/x86_64/ main.o $(FILAMENT_LIBS) -lpthread -lc++ -ldl -lm -o main
` and I only leave `main.o: main.cpp
 $(CC) -I./include/ -std=c++14 -pthread -c main.cpp` no `main.o` is produced.

Comment: Where did you get `/usr/bin/clang-cpp-8 main.cpp -L./lib/x86_64/ -I./include -lfilament -lbluegl -lbluevk -lfilabridge -lfilaflat -lutils -lpthread -lc++ -ldl -lm -std=c++14 -pthread -c` from? There's nothing like that in the Makefile.

Comment: Just combining the two lines into one and substituting `$(CC)` with my location of `clang`

Comment: The other output looks like the result of preprocessing, which is normally what you get with `clang++ -P` (or by running `cpp` directly).

Comment: As far as I can tell, this is all user error. The Makefile is fine; you're just running the wrong command (the preprocessor instead of the compiler) with the wrong arguments (passing both `-L` / `-l` and `-c`).

Comment: @melpomene ok I agree the line is wrong, but why when I use the makefile instead (literally with `>make`) no output is produced? I understand now that the generation of `main.o` has nothing to do with linking, but no `main.o` is generated which implies no final output is generated.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189405/discussion-between-melpomene-and-user8469759).