# How to show complete compiler command invocations with autotools?

Tags: c++, makefile, compilation, autotools

I'm trying to debug my autotool configuration with more verbosity, but couldn't see certain compiler command invocation. My current autotool configuration looks like this:

```
  # make distclean
  CC="${CC}"
  # CFLAGS="${CFLAGS} -miphoneos-version-min=${MIN_SDK_VERSION} -target arm64-apple-ios13.1 -arch ${ARCH} -isysroot ${SYSROOT} ${PLATFORM_CFLAGS}" \
  CFLAGS="${CFLAGS} -miphoneos-version-min=${MIN_SDK_VERSION} -target arm64-apple-ios13.1 -arch ${ARCH} -isysroot ${SYSROOT} ${PLATFORM_CFLAGS}" \
  CXX="${CXX}" \
  CXXFLAGS="${CXXFLAGS} -miphoneos-version-min=${MIN_SDK_VERSION} -target arm64-apple-ios13.1 -arch ${ARCH} -isysroot ${SYSROOT}" \
  LDFLAGS="-target arm64-apple-ios13.1 -arch ${ARCH} -miphoneos-version-min=${MIN_SDK_VERSION} ${LDFLAGS}" \
  LIBS="${LIBS}" \
  ./configure \
    --build=x86_64-apple-${DARWIN} \
    --host=${HOST} \
    --disable-shared \
    --prefix=${PREFIX} \
    --exec-prefix=${PREFIX}/platform/${PLATFORM_NAME}

  make V=1 -j8 --debug=j 
  make install
```

I have consulted a few questions such as this:

[How do I force make/GCC to show me the commands?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5820303/how-do-i-force-make-gcc-to-show-me-the-commands)

With `V=1` and `--debug=j`, I expect to see compiler commands such as

```
clang -flag value ...
```

in the screen output, but I simply don't see it.

The additional output I see is this

```
This program built for i386-apple-darwin11.3.0
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
Making all in scripts
GNU Make 3.81
Copyright (C) 2006  Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.
There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A
PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

This program built for i386-apple-darwin11.3.0
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
GNU Make 3.81
Copyright (C) 2006  Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.
There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A
PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

How should I tweak autotools to show the invocations that I want?

Comment: the output that you show says `Nothing to be done`. so there are no compiler commands to see. try changing something in the source code or run `make -B` to force a recompilation. if you still do not see the compiler command we likely will need more information from you to help. for example the actual makefile that is created by `configure`.

Comment: ... or `make clean` first, so that everything then needs to be rebuilt.