# How to get full/debug log for make command?

Tags: cmake, clang, clang++

For C/C++ build what option (if it exists) should be used to view all commands which were executed duration (make command).
For a large project, I would like to know how exactly a particular .c file was compiled? What option was provided to gcc/clang?

If I execute
./configure
make
make install
sometimes compiled commands are not visible.

Comment: What research did you do? `./configure` is not part of cmake. `What option was provided to gcc/clang?` `gcc` is not part of make. Overall, it's all _project specific_ and for _that particular project_ and _that particular build method_ there are different options. Cmake has a `--verbose` option, so _particular_ projects using cmake can use it, but every project has it's own.

Comment: Let's say I have a random project and build works fine (./configure; make; make install etc). Every files compile without error. I'm interested in compiling particular file (clang/gcc <some options> filename.c).  How I can get the proper way to compile it?

Comment: Type `gcc <some options> filename.c` in your terminal.

Comment: I want to figure out what are "<some options>". They supposed to be generated dynamically. Include paths are generated, paths to other dependencies etc. How to extra everything that is required for compilation?

Comment: Yes - so enable verbose compilation _in that project_ . What research did you do? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5820303/how-do-i-force-make-gcc-to-show-me-the-commands

Comment: I'm try to figure out how some of the files are compiling for this project https://github.com/awslabs/aws-c-common, I saw this link. Don't know way, but commands from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5820303/how-do-i-force-make-gcc-to-show-me-the-commands don't help

Comment: And that project has `CMakeLists.txt`. As said, cmake has `--verbose` option that allows building with verbosity enable. But https://stackoverflow.com/a/50995904/9072753 should work - use `make VERBOSE=1` with cmake projects.. [Here is cmake manual](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html), from it: `--verbose, -v

    Enable verbose output  .. This option can be omitted if VERBOSE environment variable or CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE cached variable is set.`