# How to catch up full gcc compile command

Tags: linux, architecture, operating-system, build-process, build-system

For example during use `make` or `b2` you can't see command, because build system  invokes gcc implicitly. I want to know full command, which build system send to compiler. conceptually. I want to catch up it independently on build system. Maybe on system level, maybe do you know another way.
OS: linux.

Comment: It should be there in your makefile.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Making make print commands before executing when NOT using CMake](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11004695/making-make-print-commands-before-executing-when-not-using-cmake)

Comment: no, I want to catch up command on system layer. Independently on build system.

Comment: I don't know what kind of build system will be used. Just wanna to know, which build command was sent to gcc. how to capture build command on system layer?