# See commands of make and all called make files thereafter

Tags: linux, makefile, build, embedded-linux, legacy-code

I am trying to decompose a make build system of a very large code base however I am unable to see every command the make invokes because it calls various make files in numerous directories outside of the current directory. I followed this answer and various other ones [Making make print commands before executing when NOT using CMake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11004695/making-make-print-commands-before-executing-when-not-using-cmake)

Though the above yielded some advancement and was quite illuminating it was not the home run I need. It offers solutions to see the commands that make invokes. Which is better than great. However, the issue is the various sub make commands that are invoked thereafter. I only see those commands as printed with no additional information of what is occurring sub make. I tried to alias make such that

```
alias make='make SHELL='\''/bin/bash -x'\'''

# or

alias make='make -n'
```

However the above fail to replace the invoked make commands with the alias. Is there another way I can dissect a large code base make build system out there?

```
> make
rmdir --ignore-fail-on-non-empty /somefolder* 2> /dev/null; true
cd /someotherfolder/; make cur-dir=somefolder dirs-to-build=somemorefolders/ env_variable another_variable someMakeRule # no output from this  make
make  TARGET=someTarget env_variable gdbinit source_dir someMakeRule; # no output from this  make
# ...
# output from first top makefile
# ...
make[1]: Nothing to be done for 'someMakeRule'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use an alias, because aliases only exist in interactive shells and are not present in non-interactive shells like the one make uses to invoke comments in recipes.  Same with shell functions.

You also cannot set the `SHELL` variable to a command that uses arguments: the value of `SHELL` must be only a command name.  You can, though, set the `.SHELLFLAGS` variable to extra options to pass to the shell.  Don't forget you need the `-c` option in addition to whatever flags you add!

Something like `.SHELLFLAGS=-xc`

If your makefiles are all properly invoking their submakes then using `make -n` as the initial invocation should Just Work.

By "properly invoking" I mean, they should *always* use the `$(MAKE)` variable when invoking sub-makes and never use a raw `make` command.

If they do not invoke sub-make properly and you cannot fix that, then the best you can do is write a shell script called `make` that does what your aliases above do, then add that to your `PATH` so it's found first.  Obviously inside the script you'll have to use a fully-qualified path to run the "real" make else you'll get infinite recursion :)

Comment: TY for quick reply. I searched for all instances of "make" and "$(MAKE)" using "grep -r expr --include=Makefile" to see what type of make was being called in the code. I thought I had found the smoking gun but it turned out that it was print statement. Whenever I do the specified query I do see $(MAKE) being used - though when I call make -n or variant, whenever the invoked command is a make command, it just says "make ..." and then doesn't expand on the commands. Also, there were a lot of hits that were "-include $(RELTOPDIR)/scripts/Makefile.submake" I don't know if that bypasses anything.

Comment: First, you won't see the option on the command line.  It's passed through the environment.  But it should still be in effect.  Second, included makefiles aren't relevant here: it works exactly as if you'd taken the text of the other makefile and inserted it at the point where the `include` is.  So all options etc. apply equally to included makefiles.

Comment: I guess, I'm not really sure exactly what the problem is you're seeing.  If your sub-make invocations are using `$(MAKE)`, and you're not changing/overriding the `MAKEFLAGS` variable, then any options like `-n` in the parent make will definitely be passed to the sub-makes.

Comment: hm. OK! I will double check it all! See my OP of what the output looks like, I have to remove things since I can't show real output.

Comment: actually you're right, I was able to get it to work - I was being dumb. I needed to do a make clean first to force a rebuild. I'm assuming it didn't show any output because it saw the object files and ended up saying nothing to do.

Comment: now that I can see where the GCC command is being executed, is it possible for me to be able to see which makefile it comes from? That will go a long way in this debugging quest.

Comment: Sure, just run `make -d`.  Or if that's too much info you can use `make --trace`.  There are also partial debug options; see https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Options-Summary.html

Answer (score 1):

You can easily trace execution with `--trace` option. Consider the following example where someone had an idea to show clean output only without any option for being verbose:

```
$ cat Makefile
all: foo
        @echo Done with $@

foo: bar
        @echo Done with $@

bar:
        @$(MAKE) -f Makefile2 bar

.SILENT:

$ cat Makefile2
bar: baz
        @echo Done with $@

baz:
        @echo Done with $@
```

Regular build does not allow to check what's happening:

```
$ make
Done with baz
Done with bar
Done with foo
Done with all
```

But `--trace` will show what is happening and why:

```
$ make --trace
Makefile:8: target 'bar' does not exist
make -f Makefile2 bar
Makefile2:5: target 'baz' does not exist
echo Done with baz
Done with baz
Makefile2:2: update target 'bar' due to: baz
echo Done with bar
Done with bar
Makefile:5: update target 'foo' due to: bar
echo Done with foo
Done with foo
Makefile:2: update target 'all' due to: foo
echo Done with all
Done with all
```